# How to call an outer scope function from within a JS module class

Tags: javascript

Why does this throw the error and what is the correct way of calling an outer (global scope) function from within a module class?

```
//models.js
export default class Model {
    log() {
        gLog();     //Uncaught ReferenceError: gLog is not defined
    }
}

//main.js
import Model from './models.js';
let m = new Model();
m.log();

function gLog() {
    console.log(1);
}
```

Comment: Why do you need to call a global function within the class method? Design-wise this is ugly. Have you thought about passing the function as a parameter to the class (constructor) instead?

Comment: The example code is a simplified version of what I have. There are a number of similar modules which get data from websockets and feed it into a common function for aggregation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A module does not have access to the objects declared in another module unless that module exports these objects. You should either include `gLog` in your `models` module (the easier way) or export it in your `main.js` then import `main.js` in `models`.

Comment: The former won't work for me, because the global function needs to be called from several modules. Won't the latter solution cause some cross-reference error?

Comment: Do you mean circular references? No it won't.